# view flipper is not flipping

Tags: android, viewflipper

**hi i have created a flip view in my activity I have 2 images that I need to get flipped ,but it is not flipping behalf I can just view my first image on the screen... I am giving my class file and xml below .. I need some solution**

```
       import android.app.Activity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.view.MotionEvent;
        import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

          public class Viewflip extends Activity 
             {
        private ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
        private float lastX;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
                     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                     setContentView(R.layout.gallery);
                     viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.view_flipper);
        }



        // Method to handle touch event like left to right swap and right to left swap
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) 
        {
                     switch (touchevent.getAction())
                     {
                            // when user first touches the screen to swap
                             case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
                             {
                                 lastX = touchevent.getX();
                                 break;
                            }
                             case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
                             {
                                 float currentX = touchevent.getX();

                                 // if left to right swipe on screen
                                 if (lastX < currentX) 
                                 {
                                      // If no more View/Child to flip
                                     if (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 0)
                                         break;

                                     // set the required Animation type to ViewFlipper
                                     // The Next screen will come in form Left and 
                    current Screen will go OUT from Right 
                                     viewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, 
                 R.anim.in_from_left);
                                     viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this,
                    R.anim.out_to_right);
                                     // Show the next Screen
                                     viewFlipper.showNext();
                                 }

                                 // if right to left swipe on screen
                                 if (lastX > currentX)
                                 {
                                     if (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 1)
                                         break;
                                     // set the required Animation type to ViewFlipper
                                     // The Next screen will come in form Right and 
              current Screen will go OUT from Left 
                                     viewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, 
                 R.anim.in_from_right);
                                     viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, 
                 R.anim.out_to_left);
                                     // Show The Previous Screen
                                     viewFlipper.showPrevious();
                                 }
                                 break;
                             }
                     }
                     return false;
                     }

                    }
```

**Xml file**

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="#000000"
          android:orientation="vertical" >

         <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="6dip" >

             <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:orientation="vertical" >

                 <ImageView
                  android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="450dp"
                  android:layout_height="450dp"
                   android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                 android:src="@drawable/scene1" />
              </LinearLayout>

              <!-- Layout 2 for 2nd Screen -->

              <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                  android:orientation="vertical" >

                   <ImageView
                  android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                   android:layout_width="450dp"
                  android:layout_height="450dp"
                   android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/scene2" />
               </LinearLayout>
               </ViewFlipper>

                 </LinearLayout>
```

**Giving my animation xml files below**

```
             **in_from_left.xml**

               <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:shareInterpolator="false">
               <translate
                android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
               android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
               android:duration="1400" />
                 </set>

               **in_from_right.xml**

              <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:shareInterpolator="false">
             <translate
               android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
              android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
                android:duration="1400" />
                </set>


                **out_to_left.xml**

             <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:shareInterpolator="false">
               <translate android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"
              android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
               android:duration="1400"/>
              </set>


                **out_to_right.xml**

              <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:shareInterpolator="false">
             <translate android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
                 android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
               android:duration="1400"/>
                 </set>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, it looks ok.

its running fine.

Problem is with the animation lines.That are not working.

Just comment the animation lines, it will work.

And if you want animation also share code for animation files.

Comment: without animation I can see my image it is also working in mine but I need animation ,I have given my animation xml files above please check ...